# Change Background color of NULLs in SSMS 2014

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I would like to change the background colour of NULL values(to Yellow  or some other) in Management Studio results Grid but cannot find a way to change it.
Currently it just displays a white background similar to other cells.
Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused because I don't see an option to change that, but mine is showing NULL values with a yellow background. Check this image and see if the last column appears yellow to you: it could just be your monitor's color settings. If it looks yellow here but not in your SSMS, make sure the value you're returning is actually SQL's NULL value and not the string 'NULL'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of "NULLS" within the grid section of SSMS by altering the color of 'Windows Tips' in the Personalization section under Control Panel for Windows.